# How can I redirect to another Twilio task using Twilio and Django?

Tags: python, django, twilio

I'm creating a chatbot and I can't redirect to a task created at the Twilio Autopilot Console.

What it does: user sends a message to the bot, the view gets called, does some stuff which I removed for clarity then redirects (or should) to an Autopilot task.

```
@twilio_view
def bot(request):
    account_sid = config('account_sid')
    auth_token = config('auth_token')

    client= Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    msgresponse = MessagingResponse()

    msgresponse.redirect(url="task://parametrizacao")

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

If I redirect to another view, django-style, it works, but I want it to redirect to a Twilio Autopilot Task...

---

I'm editing now because I've tried something else and failed.

```
            data={
             "actions": [
              {
                  "redirect": "task://parametrizacao"
              }
             ]
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
```

I thought this would work... the "parametrizacao" task is a simple one by the way:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "say": "Bem vindo à Parametrização!"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't understand.

Comment: So, in this case, does your number handle the initial incoming message and then hand off to an autopilot bot? How is your incoming webhook set up?

Comment: Yes, this is what I intend to do, but I can't get the Autopilot task to activate (I should receive the "Bem vindo à Parametrização!" message.

Comment: My incoming webhook is this 'bot' function.

I've tried different things since this post.

It seems that I have to return an Action Json, and I'm trying to do it, but, when I return a JsonResponse, I get ContentType Error.

I could only return with ContentType 'text/xml' and using TwiML, but it doesn't help me, I need to activate a new Autopilot Task and I could only use the Say tag using TwiML

Comment: Is there a reason you want to handle this outside of Autopilot before redirecting to the bot? Could it work for you to point the number at the Autopilot webhook URL in the first place? You can still get the webhook using redirect to your URL in the Autopilot response and then you can do all the responses using JSON actions as Autopilot expects.

Comment: I'ts good to know that the Actions JSON will work if the request comes from the Autopilot's redirect. 
The reason I pointed to my webhook first is to fetch the user's phone number. If the request comes from the bot's redirect, I can't do it. Or can I? Thanks for helping by the way!

Comment: Found it. UserIdentifier.
Thank you @philnash !!!!!!

Comment: Ah, that's what you needed! Glad you found it.